# Can't edit TextCtrl built from other function than __init__ (wxPython)

Tags: python, function, wxpython, textctrl

I have trouble with editing, inputting to or even clicking a TextCtrl or actually any other widget that is not built in the **init** function.

Let's say I have this bit:

```
class firstpanel(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
```

....

```
def receivetext(self, event):
    panel = wx.Panel(self,size=wx.Size(850,650))
    wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, self.textfromsomewhereelse, (365, 145))
```

I do see the TextCtrl with the appropriate value in my GUI Frame but I can't modify it. 
It's exactly like I have an invisible layer over it that is not letting me through.

I say I'm missing something very basic and it's very embarresing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `receivetext` you create an instance of `wx.TextCtrl`, but you do not add it to the `panel`. You also do not keep a reference to the instance, so it will be destroyed immediately by the garbage collector.

```
class MyFrame1 (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyFrame1, self).__init__()
        fluid_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.m_textCtrl1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        fluid_sizer.Add(self.m_textCtrl1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(fluid_sizer)
        self.Layout()
```

The example shows that a `wx.BoxSizer` was created and an `wx.TextCtrl`. The reference to the text control is stored as `self.m_textCtrl`. The text control is than added to the sizer, making it visible.